# Is there a convention for how to handle data points that fall on the fences when determining outliers?

Tags: descriptive-statistics, outliers, interquartile

If I have a data set where a given measurement is equal to Q1 - 1.5(IQR), is there a convention for how to handle this? Should this be considered an outlier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Moore's *The Basic Practice of Statistics*, "Call an observation a suspected outlier if it falls *more than* 1.5*IQR above the third quartile or below the first quartile." This is the  gold standard resource for me. Thus, a value lying on 1.5*IQR below $Q_1$ would NOT be an outlier.

Comment: Thank you for this. I recognise it is a rare instance but it is nice to find examples where statisticians or educators have been precise about this.

Comment: Difficult to be precise about a rule of thumb, particularly one that is not accepted in all fields of statistical application. In my field, ecology, "outliers" are required to have a cause (typically typos, broken equipment, detection limits, mixing of two phenomena etc), not only an extreme position in the ecdf.

Comment: @Carsten I agree, but I believe the OP is just looking for common practices on this particular rule of thumb. It's like all of Statistics—we have to have rules, but also have some reasonable wiggle room.

Answer (score 1):

A good but complicated way to find out if the data point is outlier or not is to conduct a diagnostic for leverage and influence of this point.

Some examples and explanation can be found here: https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat462/node/87/